# Get the closest img title and set as field title

Tags: jquery

I am going to explain my question by an example:

Here is my html code:

```
<td>Name<a href="http://manual"><span><img src="x" width="15" title="The name></span></a></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" size="93" ></td>
```

What I want to do is get the closest img title to my input field, and set it as the field title. The purpose is basically check all the page's form fields and set the closest image title to their title, if the title has not been set.

What I have done so far:

```
$('form').find(':input').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('type') != "hidden" ){

        var title = $(this).siblings('td').find("img").attr("title");
        $(this).attr('title', title);

    }
});
```

But no success. I'd be grateful if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks,

Comment: The [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector will be handy.

Comment: At least accept an answer

Comment: at least let me wake up to accept an answer!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').find(':input').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('type') != "hidden" ){
        var title = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').find("img").attr("title");
        $(this).attr('title', title);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
    $('form').find(':input').each(function(){
       var image = $(this).closest('tr').find('img');
    });
```

This will search for the closest tr tag and search for images inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').find(':input').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('type') != "hidden" ){
        var title = $(this).parents('td').prev().find('img').attr('title');
        $(this).attr('title', title);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kanishka, the most useful answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').find(':input').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('type') != "hidden" ){
        var title = $(this).closest("tr").find("img").attr("title");
        $(this).attr('title', title);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find all form inputs without title, which aren't hidden. Then search the `img` in the current row and copy it's title

```
$('form :input:not([title]):not([type="hidden"])').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).closest('tr').find('img').attr('title');
  $(this).attr('title', title);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRb45/) for testing.

Comment: just one thing. there might be a case that there is no img specifically close to a field. in that case is there a way to stop it from picking up the closest img (because it does) and its not right!

Comment: @ComeRun If it finds an `img`, it must be in the current `tr`. What's the criteria for this or can you show an example, where this happens?

Comment: here is a good example

<tr>

<td>Name<a href="http://manual"><span><img src="x" width="15" title="The name></span></a></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" size="93" ></td>

<td><input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="80" size="93" ></td>

</tr>

As you can see we have two td in a tr. the first one has got a img and the title needs to be picked up. but the second one, no img hence to title needs to be set.

Comment: @ComeRun From that, I would say Kanishka's answer should fit your requirement best, because he looks for the preceding `td`.